# django orm foreign key latest data using filter query

Tags: django, django-orm

```
    class Schedule(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(USER, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

        area = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)



    area = Schedule.objects.values("area").annotate(latest=Max('created_at')).values("area")
    latest = Schedule.objects.values("area").annotate(latest=Max('created_at')).values("latest")

    Schedule.objects.filter(created_at__in=latest, area__in=area)
```

I got the value I want.

However, I am uneasy when I filter with ForeignKey and DateTimeField. Can't there be a better way?

Also, can't you make it cleaner other than the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can create a `Manager` for your Model and use `selected_related` feature, it will create quick query for you, and it`s ready "out-of-the-box" Django solution. Plz see [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/) docs.

Here`s example based on your code

In Model.py something like

```
class SheduleManager(model.Manager):
   def all_prefetched_data(self):
      qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.select_related(
            'area_set'
        )
        return qs
```

in the same Model.py you need to assign your manager in Shedule model

```
listing = SheduleManager
```

Now in view you can sort db items by creation date, query with the ForiegnKey fetching through all your db. You also can display result, for example in `your_template.html` with the dictionary `b_list`

view.py

```
def GetList(request):
    sh_list = Schedul.listing.all().order_by('-created_at')
    
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'b_list': sh_list})
```